# How to display an image with java spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring, image, spring-mvc

I'm trying to display an image with spring MVC in a maven project.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.simslay</groupId>
  <artifactId>tutoriel-web-spring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tutoriel-web-spring Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>tutoriel-web-spring</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is my web.xml :

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

        <!-- Declaration de la servlet de Spring et de son mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My dispacher-servlet.xml :

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.developpez.rpouiller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/vues/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
</beans>
```

I have an image in that folder : src/main/resources/images/image.jpg

I try to display the previous image in src/main/webapp/vues/bonjour.jsp in differents ways :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>bonjour</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img alt="image" src="/resources/images/image.jpg" />
            <img src="/tutoriel-web-spring/resources/images/image.jpg" alt="image" />
            <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/image.jpg" />" alt="image" />
            <img src="<c:url value="/images/image.jpg" />" alt="image" />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

But no way to display it (only alternate text is displaying). Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by putting my image folder in webapp/resources. And the image tag is :

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/image.jpg" />" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to refer to the absolute path of the image , regardless of the URL used to invoke your JSP, you'll have to use an abolute path `src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/image.jpg"` so src is going from the context root of your maven project.

Comment: I've just tried this (<img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/resources/images/image.jpg" alt="image" />) but no result.

Comment: Well, that is not what i posted. You should have it like this:
`<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/image.jpg" alt = "image" />`.

Comment: I've got these errors : javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a type,Type javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type and regardless of this error the image won't display.

Comment: I've resolved the errors by adding some dependency and the image is still not displaying.

Comment: Is resources folder under src/main/resources ? If so try moving images folder into webapp folder and change path to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/ima‌​ge.jpg`

Comment: Yes it is. I've tried to move the folder and rename src content but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set like this 
$('#id').attr('src','/resources/images/'+imageName); //Dynamically

Answer (score -1):

Run the program in Google Chrome, press F12, navigate to the image and see the path of the image. If the path of the image is correct and the image is still not showing, copy the image again to the image folder.